# mat-select doesn't display until i click on it

Tags: angular, angular-material

mat-select doesn't display until i click on it, also does not display the value.

HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="select" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Flex property</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose property" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let prop of flexProperties" [value]="prop.value">
      {{prop.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
  selectedItem: string;



 flexProperties: flexProps[] = [
    {value: 'flexDirection', viewValue: 'flex-direction'},
    {value: 'justifyContent', viewValue: 'justify-content'},
    {value: 'flexWrap[enter image description here][1]', viewValue: 'flex-wrap'},
    {value: 'flexFlow', viewValue: 'flex-flow'},
    {value: 'order', viewValue: 'order'},
    {value: 'alignItems', viewValue: 'align-items'},
    {value: 'alignSelf', viewValue: 'align-self'},
    {value: 'alignContent', viewValue: 'align-content'},
    {value: 'flexGrow', viewValue: 'flex-grow'},
    {value: 'flexShrink', viewValue: 'flex-shrink'},
    {value: 'flexBasic', viewValue: 'flex-basic'}
  ]
```

This how select looks after selected option
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Yt1.png

Comment: Are you asking about how to set the default value in a mat-select element?

Comment: Im asking why my mat-select invisible until i click on it

Comment: If it is completely invisible (no border or anything), that sounds like a bug. If its just that there's no text shown in the mat-select box, then that's just a configuration issue of setting the initial value. It sounds like you are experiencing the first issue (completely invisible), in which case a minimium reproducible example would help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show some message in your mat-select, you can do it:

```
<mat-form-field class="select" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Flex property</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose property" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
    <mat-option>Choose property</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let prop of flexProperties" [value]="prop.value">
      {{prop.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```