# Angular mat-select invisible until you click on it, how to set a default value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having tree issues related with making mat-selected work (please don't make me ask 3 questions since they are all related)

1. The control is not visible until I click on the empty space
2. No matter what I select the selected option is not showing (not keeping it)
3. Maybe first issue can be solved by having a default selected option

**Ignore the red message below the button is just a reminder**

[image]

When I click the empty space the select options appear.

[image]

After making a selection the control is in invalid mode

[image]

There are not any console/angular errors

Here is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-round',
  templateUrl: './game-round.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-round.component.css']
})
export class GameRoundComponent implements OnInit {
  moves : string[] = [];
  selectedMove: string = 'Rock';

  currentRoundInfo = new FormGroup({
    moves: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
  constructor(
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.backService.getGameMoves()
      .subscribe((data: string[]) => {
        this.moves = data;
        //this.currentRoundInfo.setValue({moves : data}) ;
        console.log(`getGameMoves:${this.moves}`);
      });
      
    //trying to set a defult value
      this.currentRoundInfo.setValue({
        moves: 'Paper'
      });

  }

  moveSelected(move: string) {
    console.log("moveSelected:" + move) ;
    this.selectedMove = move ;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("next") ;
    
  }
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="full-width-centered">
  <form [formGroup]="currentRoundInfo" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="full-width" >
      <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Select your move:</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selectedMove" formControlName="moves" placeholder="test placeholder" (selectionChange)="moveSelected($event.value)">
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let m of moves" [value]="m">
            {{m}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I found this other question for firt issue but no answer was provided.

[mat-select doesn't display until i click on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164144/mat-select-doesnt-display-until-i-click-on-it)

I have also tried many other similar answers with no luck (changing the floatlabel to always and setting a placeholder value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like angular-material default style for the select is not working so I decided to override it.

```
.mat-select {
    border: 1px solid lightseagreen !important ;
    background: lightseagreen;
    height: 30px !important;
}
```

Setting the default was working, but since select was invisible I could not see that

```
//Set de default value
this.currentRoundInfo.setValue({
    movesControl: 'rock' 
});
```

To keep the selected value just store in an component property and bind it to the select:

```
<mat-select [(value)]="selectedMove"
```

**UPDATE** : reinstalling angular/material and restarting `ng serve` also helped

So after more styling this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a zone. A zone provides an execution context that persists across async tasks.

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
```

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private zone: NgZone
) { }
```

```
this.backService.getGameMoves()
  .subscribe((data: string[]) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.moves = data;
    });
    //this.currentRoundInfo.setValue({moves : data}) ;
    console.log(`getGameMoves:${this.moves}`);
  });
```

This should work to fix your issue. I cannot test to verify since I don't have access to your service or a code playground link to test in, but I have tested in a similar scenario of my own.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my case reinstalling angular material solved the problem, se my answer

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez While it is good that you found a solution that works for your needs, Angular considers using a Zone as the preferred solution. If you are not using reactive forms for your component, you will not have access to the additional async functionality. For any other users looking for solutions to the same issue, they will need a solution that works more generally. This solution also works for when an element using *ngIf has its logic status changed in an observable subscriber, which is likely not to be reflected in the layout.

Comment: Feel free to try to replicate the problem and test your solution - here is the code-repo https://github.com/mauriciogracia/GoD_frontend and it depends on a backend https://github.com/mauriciogracia/GoD_backend

Comment: As far as I remember I'm using reactive forms.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Yes, but if someone else comes here looking for a solution to the same issue, but is not using reactive forms, they will have a solution to their problem where they do not need to add reactive forms.